# MVC 4 - Master Layout dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, dll

I'm able to make my own Layout page in a single solution but when creating another solution I want to be able to use a common layout page so I don't have to have 5 applications all with the exact same layout page when I could have 5 applications that all reference a dll with the layout inside of it.

`MvcApplication1` = Common Layout
`MvcApplication2` = Application I want to use the `MvcApplication1` layout for.

I have 2 test applications open currently. One of them is the master layout application that has the layout with the CSS styles I need for application 2. I built application 1 and put the dll on my desktop. I then went to application 2 which is empty except for the Home controller with a Index view. I include the application 1 dll and inside my application 2 _ViewStart.cshtml I put in

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Plugin/MvcApplication1.dll/MvcApplication1/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Now I get this error:

```
The layout page "~/Plugin/MvcApplication1.dll/MvcApplication1/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
could not be found at the following path:
"~/Plugin/MvcApplication1.dll/MvcApplication1/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".
```

**Question:** How can I use my MvcApplication1's _Layout page on my MvcApplication2 using a dll?

**Edit:** I cannot use external tools.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [Razor Generator](https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/), to create pre-compiled views. (Views are normally only compiled at runtime.) You can then stored these views in a class library that both projects can reference. You'll need to do some additional work to wire everything up, so that the other projects know to look for compiled views in addition to views on the filesystem, but there's documentation there on how to do all that.

Comment: I can't use that. Any other way? I'm looking at using a dll.

Comment: Why can't you use that? And, no. The whole purpose of that library's existence is to allow you to do exactly this with Razor views.

Comment: And, the result *will* be a DLL. You create a class library, add your views to that and it compiles into a DLL. If your projects are in the same solution, you can just add a reference to the class library project, but if you need to use it in a different solution, you just copy the compiled DLL over to that project

Comment: First, I just linked you to the project page. There's a nuget package you can install, directly in Visual Studio, so no need to download code. However, that's kind of an odd restriction, anyways. What in the world would prevent you from downloading code?

Comment: Company does not allow it.

Comment: They may prevent you from downloading archives, but not code. Code is just text, and unless your corporate policy is so strict that you can't even view a text file, then there's nothing stopping you from downloading "code". Like I said though, it's actually better to get it through nuget, and if your company is blocking that, they need to stop, as you're essentially crippled nowadays as a .NET developer without nuget.

Comment: MVC itself is an "external tool" now!